# htaccess redirect url to page

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I want to redirect a particular page using a 301 but my htaccess is also redirecting pages that contain the same start.

Example:

I want to redirect:

> http://domain.com/advantage

To:

> http://domain.com/index.php?page=some advantage

My current rule is

```
RewriteRule ^advantage "index.php?page=some advantage" [L,R=301]
```

This rule also redirects

> http://domain.com/advantage-form.php

To the "some advantage" page

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`^advantage` should be `^advantage$`

i.e. Instead of "Start, then advantage" it should be "Start, then advantage, then End".

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/mod_rewrite-tips-and-tricks.html) site is an expert on using mod_rewrite. Have a look at it. He is got lot of resources, if you are dealing with lot of rewrite rules. However whatever David said should work for the above question